# Suppress test_that output "Test passed :)"

Tags: r, testthat

An update to the test_that package (version 3.0.2) in R results in default output for passing a test as:

> Test passed :)

This is cute initially, but annoying in a model which performs the test every iteration several thousand times.

How can this message be suppressed?

Comment: You may wrap with `capture.output` to an object

Comment: @akrun I would like the output to print if there is an error, but not if the test is passed

Comment: I updated based on your comment.  Please check

Comment: Answers the question, though an argument within the function would be preferable: test_that(..., verbose=F)

Comment: You could extend the core function in github, raise a pull request for acceptance.  It makes sense to have the `verbose` argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to extract the message as a string and divert it to an object.  We can use `capture.output`

```
out <- capture.output(test_that("trigonometric functions match identities", {
 expect_equal(sin(pi / 4), 1 / sqrt(2))
expect_equal(cos(pi / 4), 1 / sqrt(2))
expect_equal(tan(pi / 4), 1)
}))
```

But functions that suppress the messages would still prints the message

[image]

---

We could make a condition after capturing with `grep` to print or not

```
f1 <- function(x) if(any(!grepl('passed', x))) cat(x, sep='\n')

out1 <- capture.output(test_that("trigonometric functions match identities", {

  expect_equal(sin(pi / 4), 1 / sqrt(2))
  expect_equal(cos(pi / 4), 1 / sqrt(2))
  expect_equal(tan(pi / 4), 1)
  expect_equal(sin(pi / 4), 1)

   }))

f1(out) # nothing prints
f1(out1)
#── Failure (???): trigonometric functions match identities ─────────────────────
#sin(pi/4) not equal to 1.
#1/1 mismatches
#[1] 0.707 - 1 == -0.293
```